# Angular get request 415 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get

Hi guys I'm trying to make a get request with angular and I don't seem to be able to. It fly's in both jquery and postman. But I always get a 415 unsupported media type when I make a get request in angular. Please help me.

Here's my code in angular and jquery.

```
            var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: url,
            headers : {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data.ExceptionMessage);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
```

//--------------------------------------------------

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function( err ) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

And here is the error

GET https://oc4showcaseservice.azurewebsites.net/api/getdocumentlist/?localList=false&regionId=&searchTerm=&tagFilters= 415 (Unsupported Media Type)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:93r @ angular.min.js:89g @ angular.min.js:86(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:119r.$eval @ angular.min.js:133r.$digest @ angular.min.js:130r.$apply @ angular.min.js:134g @ angular.min.js:87T @ angular.min.js:92w.onload @ angular.min.js:93
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://oc4showcaseservice.azurewebsites.net/api/tag?$filter=tagType_Id%20eq%20%27645685D7-01C5-414B-BF15-7E37A366EDC6%27. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: What's the `url`? Is it in the same domain of the Angular app?

Comment: What is the return value from web service? it should be JSON. check the web service.

Comment: try removing the contenType from header while making the request

Comment: I've try removing headers, It's not the same domain the url. But jquery manages to return data. The content type from the server is application json. Belive me I've try many things. It's clearly a angular problem

Comment: post your server side code as well

Comment: Sorry but I don't have access to it

Comment: Does anybody have a clue why jquery works but not angular?